# How do I get variables generated in one class to another?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have tried to use `Inheritance` but it did not arrear to work, furthermore I tried using `Composition` but with equally little succes. The individual arrays is read from a text-file, which makes it specific data. The code is as follows:

```
The generating code: 
public static void ReadText(string[] args)
    {
        Dictionary<string, int[]> rows = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("txt.txt");

        int counter = 0;

        foreach (string s in lines)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine(s);
            string[] arr = s.Split(' '); 
            int[] array = new int[arr.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = Convert.ToInt32(arr[i]); 
            }


            string key = "M_array_" + counter++;
            rows.Add(key, array);
            //ShowArray(array);

        }

        foreach (string key in rows.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {String.Join(" ", rows[key])}");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

How do I call `M_array_1` , `M_array_2` etc. in an other class? Usually then I call one varibel from another class I use `inheritance`:

```
Class_example CE = new Class_example();
```

Or `Composition`:

```
public class wheel{}
public class car : wheel{}
```

Comment: It's not clear why you've got a dictionary at all... wouldn't it be better to just pass an array to the other code? But it's also not clear whether your problem actually has anything to do with the specific data (the array/dictionary in this case) or whether you don't know how to get *any* information from one class to another. As we can't see what your other code is, that's tricky to help you with. Perhaps your `ReadText` method should *return* an `int[][]` or a `List<int[]>`?

Comment: I'm not sure you are grasping what inheritance and composition are judging by your final comments.  You should probably explore that a little further.

Answer (score -1):

Make your dictionary static and accessible from other classes?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static Dictionary<string, int[]> Rows = new Dictionary<string, int[]>(); // initialize just in case
    public static void ReadText(string[] args)
    {
        Rows = new Dictionary<string, int[]>();

        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("txt.txt");

       ...
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Make sure you have done MyClass.ReadText(args) beforehands
        // then you can call the int array
        int[] m_array_1 = MyClass.Rows["M_array_1"];
        int[] m_array_2 = MyClass.Rows["M_array_2"];

       // or
       foreach (string key in MyClass.Rows.Keys)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"{key}: {String.Join(" ", rows[key])}");
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you not just return the data from a method.  This two step approach is error prone.  You shouldn't have to call `ReadText` and then call `Rows`.

Comment: thanks for downvote, I am just giving a suggestion to fulfill his requirements to let other class access the int array, not trying to do the easy way or something with lesser error prone.